# Javascript pattern (regular expression) for input type text in jsp page

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, user-input

I am trying the below pattern to test the text mentioned like ex: ZKB9/20320216/alphanumerictext. Its not working. I have never used regular expressions and appreciate your help. JSP code below:

```
<input type="text" value="" size="40" id="txtABCNo" name="txtABCNo" required pattern="[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]\/[0-9]{8}$\/^\w+$"></input>
```

Comment: Till `[0-9]{8}` it was all good then you added `$` which was not proper as it signifies end of string which clearly is not so.

Then again you have the wrong symbol in the wrong place: `^` unless inside square brackets signifies start of string; inside square brackets its a negation operator. So `^\w+$` does not work at all.

In JS, the regex you're looking for might be: `/^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]\/[0-9]{8}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g`.

Answer (score 0):

ZKB9/20320216/alphanumerictext

This is Java RegEX for above Code:     `[A-Z0-9]{4}/[0-9]{8}/[a-z]*`

```
<input type="text" value="" size="40" id="txtABCNo" name="txtABCNo" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4}/[0-9]{8}/[a-z]*" title="Enter the Code like this :: ZKB9/20320216/alphanumerictext ">
```

Comment: Yes. I need equivalent java script pattern to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern that you tried, you can omit the `^` before matching the word characters `\w`. You can also omit the `$` at the end, as the pattern is anchored using the pattern property.

```
[A-Z]{3}[0-9]\/[0-9]{8}\/\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/knkxsd/1)